# the centering of the body/maindiv disappears when resizing the window smaller

Tags: html, css, centering

Hello i have a small css problem... just can´t figure it out, and i have already googled it, so; i have a main div, with divs in it and my thought is that when it opens om a smaller screen the divs should appear under each other, and it does.. my problem is that on a computer screen it is centered in the window, but as soon i resize the window so the first divs "jumps" to the next row, it seems like the centering disappears and it it stuck to the left side again..... please help... i want the divs to always be centered!

js fiddle:  jsfiddle.net/VCk2x/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VCk2x/

Comment: Have  you tried resetting your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that seems to do what you want :

HTML :

```
<ul class="int">
<li><div class="pic">boite 1</div></li>
<li><div class="pic">boite 2</div></li>
<li><div class="pic">boite 3</div></li>
<li><div class="pic">boite 4</div></li>
<li><div class="pic">boite 5</div></li>
<li><div class="pic">boite 6</div></li>
<li><div class="pic">boite 7</div></li>
<li><div class="pic">boite 8</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
div.pic {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 250px;
    height: 180px;
    background: #ff9933;
    margin:0;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: green;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

ul.int {
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:4% auto ;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.int li {
    margin: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle; 
}

ul.int.droite {direction:rtl;}
```

here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CMUjT/

Comment: Thank you!! :) I could figure it out with your code as help! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to accomplish a responsive layout this way, you're doing it wrong.

I'd suggest reading up on some basic [responsive tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/).

To center your #mainDiv, however:

```
#mainDiv {
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I din't understand your problem but I think your blocks should not be displayed together as inline, if this is right. Add the `width: {your width}px;` in `#mainDiv` also set to displayed as block.